# Mat Single channel Element Access

Tags: opencv

Using three channel Mat we can access element like

```
Mat draw(480, 480, CV_8UC3);
Vec3b pix(255,0,0);
draw.at<Vec3b>(i,j)=pix;
```

But in the case of single channel Mat like

```
 Mat draw(480, 480, CV_8UC1);
```

how can I access Mat element. I already tried some thing like

```
 draw.at<float>(i,j)=255;
```

but wrong result. Am I wrong in the above case ?, any help will appreciated.....

Thanks in advance.............

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That `draw.at<float>(i,j)=255;` should be

```
draw.at<uchar>(i,j)=255;
```

You have declared the Mat as type 8 bit unsigned char, 1 channel:

```
Mat draw(480, 480, CV_8UC1);
```

so trying to write a 4 byte quantity to a single byte container is going to cause not only incorrect result, but probably corru[tion of other data structures.

The following is going to write (255.0) to 4 bytes not 1:

```
draw.at<float>(i,j)=255;
```

Comment: @user2151446 could this error produce undefined behavior in Release mode with full optimization? just curious...

Comment: @William Yes - the write draw.at<float>(479,479)=255 is to an address well passed the allocated image buffer so behavior from there is undefined as at() doesn't do any checking in release mode.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to use CV_8UC1 then accessing an element in the Mat would be like this

`(draw.at<Vec3b>(i,j)).val[k]=255;`

where K is the channel number (0 to 3)